# Using XIB file, but won't call viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, xcode

I have created an empty project, and i have included xib file but when i run the app the viewDidLoad does not get called.

```
    //
    //  ViewController.m
    //  InstantForum
    //
    //  Created by trikam patel on 28/08/2014.
    //  Copyright (c) 2014 trikam patel. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        UIView *loginSignupView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, 68)];
        loginSignupView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:56.0f/255 green:56.0f/255 blue:57.0f/255 alpha:1.0f];
        [self.view addSubview:loginSignupView];

    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

### UPDATE

I get this output in the console:

```
2014-08-28 23:00:57.709 InstantForum[19545:60b] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

Comment: How do you create an instance of ViewController?

Comment: @almas, viewcontroller was created when creating the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is not properly initialized. The "window" is empty and not attached to any view controller.

In your appdelegate, check if a rootViewController is being set for window. It should be something like...

```
ViewController *vc=[[ViewController alloc] @"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController=vc
self.window.makeKeyAndVisible=YES;
```

The above technically tells the appdelegate to attach viewcontroller's view to the app's window. And provided the ViewController is properly created (it's view is attached to the controller) it should show.

Answer (score 0):

Where are your `ViewController` and `Window` defined?  If in the XIB file, check they are hooked up in the Connections Inspector.  If not hooked up, Ctrl-Drag (in the Document Outline) from the window to your ViewController and make the connection to `RootViewController`.

If the `ViewController` and window are defined in the AppDelegate, you achieve the same results with

```
self.window.rootViewController = viewcontroller;
```